# How to render a notification from a global function - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I am trying to utilize `notistack` for `ReactJs` and I would like to display the notification by calling a helper function but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Here is the standard code required to use the component:

App component:

```
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';

<SnackbarProvider maxSnack={3}>
    <App />
</SnackbarProvider>
```

Component that displays the notification:

```
import { withSnackbar } from 'notistack';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleNetworkRequest = () => {
     fetchSomeData()
        .then(() => this.props.enqueueSnackbar('Successfully fetched the data.'))
        .catch(() => this.props.enqueueSnackbar('Failed fetching data.'));
  };

  render(){
     //...
  };

};

export default withSnackbar(MyComponent);
```

I would like to place the `enqueueSnackbar('my notification message')` inside a class or some kind of helper function so that I can call the helper function from anywhere in the `react` app to display a message without having to wrap the export of a component with `withSnackbar(MyComponent);`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this via Context API like so:

- create a context object which holds the `enqueueSnackbar` function
- Then pass it from the uppermost App comp or any other parent comp
- Access it anywhere inside any child component and invoke it as needed

Some pseduo code:

```js
// context.js

import React from 'react';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';


const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

const snackbarContext = React.createContext({ enqueueSnackbar });

export default snackbarContext;
```

Then wrap a parent component in the tree with this context's provider like so:

```js
//parent.js

import SnackbarContext from './context.js'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SnackbarContext.Provider>
      <SomeParentComponent />
    </SnackbarContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now it can be used inside a dummy child component like so:

```js
// child.js

import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import SnackbarContext from './context.js'

const DummyChild = ()=>{
  const {enqueueSnackbar} = useContext(SnackbarContext);
  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Dummy Component with snackbar invocation</h1>
       <button onClick={() => enqueueSnackbar('Wohoooo')}>Show Snackbar</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```